# Elementor showing Server Error(403 error.)

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am trying to update my footer using Elementor in the WordPress but it's showing me the Server Error (403 error) and I am getting this error on the footer updating only not on any other pages.

Please help me to sort out this error and thanks in advance!

[check out the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhm2N.jpg)

Comment: Are you using any security plugin? Try with a deactivating plugin. Also try deactivating other plugins, except the elementor.

Comment: Hi @Earid I am not using any security plugin and I tried with deactivating other plugins but that also doesn't work.
I am getting this error on this page only not any other pages, I can easily edit and update other pages.

Comment: We need more information to be able to help, e.g. Did you make changes to the code,css, widgets etc? What were the specific changes that you made? What is the new footer supposed to do on this page? We're not mind readers, we can't help with a problem that we can't see :)

Comment: I have something similar with a page, I delete that entirely, and recreate that. You can save a copy of the footer as template.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I didn't make any changes anywhere and this is the error only, I am trying to update link which I gave to "Hire Us" text and other than this I can edit and do whatever I want to do in here but I am getting Server Error when I click on "Update".

Comment: if this isn’t caused by a coding problem then Stack Overflow isn’t the place to ask. This site is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: I have similar issue and for headers only, footer and other pages are working fine.

Answer (score 5):

I solved that issue by disabling ModSecurity from Cpanel.
If you then still have problems contact your hosting, they will probably disable firewall or security for your domain and you can check.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

found solution for my case
if I used "custom html" block with "script" inside and script had "not" operator in it (like this "!$(this)") - it caused a 403 error